# Angular Material Datepicker changes month to 01 (jan) when user types 13 in edge and ie browser, How do i restrict it

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer, angular-material, microsoft-edge

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

## Before

[image: Before typing]

## After

[image: After typing]

When a user types 13 in the month field, Edge and Ie Browsers converts then to 01 (Jan) and similarly 14 to 02 (Feb). It works fine in other browsers like chrome. How can we fix this?

Comment: `It works fine in other browsers like chrome` ← Define it works fine? Do you mean it allows for the invalid month and keeps the input? Is that your expected behavior for IE Edge as well? You could add your own validation / checks by subscribing to `dateChange` and/or `dateInput`.

Comment: Yes, I had a validation if the user enters the invalid month and date, but as edge and ie converts 13 to 1  before checking logic!

Comment: Yes i agree we can use datechange and/or dateInput, as in this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/angular/odrmqdenkrv?file=app%2Fdatepicker-events-example.html open this url in both the browsers like chrome and edge and we can the input and change is null in chrome but we can see the change and input in edge.

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? From your description, do you mean in the Edge and IE browser, it will change 13 to 01 (Jan), but in the Chrome browser, it will not change the value, right?